# Insert a text string into a specific position of another text string in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

If column A lists the following yourusername and column B contains different values such as variant1, variant2, etc. how can I create a formula that results in yourvariant1username yourvariant2username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have

```
John    Apple
Jane    Banana
```

then in column C,
`=B1 & A1`  will produce

```
AppleJohn
BananaJane
```

If you wish to take same username field, you can put $ in front, like `$A$1`which will keep the same cell reference.

**EDIT: based on comment:**

(below you may need to replace ";" with "," if you have an English-version of Excel.

Given that there is one distinct character in one column:

```
   Col A         Col B             Col C
--------     --------------       ------------
    1234     analyt+@gmail.com     analyt+1234@gmail.com
    5678     prefix@gmail.com      prefix5678@gmail.com
```

Col C could be achieved by something like this:

```
   =LEFT(B1;FIND("@";B1)-1 & A1 & RIGHT(B1;FIND("@";B1)-1)
```

Alternative versions :

Insert after 3 characters

```
   =LEFT(B1;3) & A1 & RIGHT(B1;LENGTH(B1)-3)
```

If one string always contains "+" or some other marker:

```
   =REPLACE(B1;SEARCH("+@";B1); 2 ; A1 & "+@")
 
   (of if the "+@" string is stored in a cell, like F1) :

   =REPLACE(B1;SEARCH(  $F$1 ;B1); LENGTH($F$1) ; A1 & $F$1)
```

(the string to search/replace can of course also be a reference to a cell containing this string)

This should give you enough to build on. If ok, please accept as a solution.

Comment: So what if I have an email address and I want to insert a plus address field within it. So if one column contains 4377 and I want to insert that within an email address. analytics+@email.com becomes analytics+4377@email.com

Comment: Or to refer to your example I want to create BanAppleana